# Count and OR clause in a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a pretty simple query that doesn't act as expected.

```
# Retrieve news                                                               
news = News.objects.filter(available=True)                                    
if area:                                                                      
    news = news.annotate(Count('areas')).filter(Q(areas__count=0)
                                                |Q(areas=area))
```

I expect to have news with no area affected or with the specified area. But i get none of them.

When I print the query I get:

```
SELECT "chimere_news"."id", "chimere_news"."title", 
       "chimere_news"."available","chimere_news"."date", "chimere_news"."content",
       COUNT("chimere_news_areas"."area_id") AS "areas__count"
FROM "chimere_news"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "chimere_news_areas" ON ("chimere_news"."id" = "chimere_news_areas"."news_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "chimere_news_areas" T4 ON ("chimere_news"."id" = T4."news_id")
WHERE ("chimere_news"."available" = True  AND (T4."area_id" = 1 ))
GROUP BY "chimere_news"."id", "chimere_news"."title", "chimere_news"."available", 
"chimere_news"."date", "chimere_news"."content"
HAVING COUNT("chimere_news_areas"."area_id") = 0
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a Django bug?

Comment: Areas is a ManyToManyField inside News?

Comment: Yes, it is (actually a subclass of ManyToManyField in order to change the widget)

Comment: One obvious problem I can see is `areas=area`. You should be using `areas_in=[area.id]`. Secondly, instead of using `areas__count=0` can you annotate `c=Count('areas')` and use that instead?

Comment: `areas=area` usually don't poses problem. I have tried to be explicit as you are suggesting but it doesn't work better. The fact is that the 2 clauses Q(areas__count=0) and Q(areas=area) works fine individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the count to compare to zero, then try using `isnull` instead.

```
if area:                                                                      
    news = news.filter(Q(areas__isnull=True)|Q(areas=area))
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! I still don't know if my first piece code show a Django bug that I should report but I go with this solution for now.

Comment: Glad it worked! I think you may have been encountering [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11293) (or at least something similar) with your initial attempt.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be related to this issue.